# How to manage ajax request for Lazy loading On window scroll when scrolling is middle of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Lazy loading in my Project. using https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/lazy-loading-in-asp-net-mvc/ refrence I want ajax call after scroll and after images upload with slow mode and dont want to scroll next till loader show i am using:-

```
 if ($(window).scrolltop() == $(document).height() -  $(window).height()) { 
     loadprojectdata(url); 
     }
```

this code working when my scroll goes to bottom so i cant see loader image. every time when i reach bottom ajax request working but I want it works after fisrt images loads

This is my html:-

```
 @model IEnumerable<TechbitOfficalWebApp.Models.AlbumViewModel>

<!-- ==============================================
**Inner Banner**
=================================================== -->
<section class="inner-banner career-banner new-carrer-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contents">
            <h1>Our Gallery</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <span>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</span></p>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- ==============================================
**Portfolio**
=================================================== -->
<section class="portfolio-outer padding-lg">

    <!-- Start portfolio filter -->
    <div class="container text-center main-album-container">

        <!-- end portfolio filter -->

        <ul class="row portfolio clearfix album-wrapper">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <li class="col-6 col-md-3">

                    <a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="GetImages('@item.AlbumName')">
                        <div class="inner" style='background-image: url(@item.AlbumImages.ThumbImage)'>
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <p>images(1)</p>

                            </div>

                            <figure><img src="@item.AlbumImages.ThumbImage" class="img-responsive" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="album-view"></div>
                    <h1 class="album-name"><a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick="GetImages('@item.AlbumName')">@item.AlbumName </a></h1>
                </li>
            }
       </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="container image-album-container"></div>  
    <div id="reach"></div>
    <div class="service-loader" style="display:none">
        <img src="~/Content/images/new-Images/doublering.gif" />
    </div>
</section>
<!-- ==============================================
**Portfolio**
==============
```

===================================== -->

This is my js:-

```
var albumName = "";
    var items = [];
    var page = 0,
    var url = '/home/GetImages';
    inCallback = false,
    isReachedScrollEnd = false;
    var thisWindow = $(window);
    var scrollHandler = function () {
        if ($(window).scrolltop() == $(document).height() -  $(window).height()) { 
         loadprojectdata(url); 
         } 
    }

    function loadProjectData(loadMoreRowsUrl) {

        if (page > -1 && !inCallback) {
            inCallback = true;
            page++;
            $(".service-loader").show();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: loadMoreRowsUrl,
                data: { pageNum: page, Album: albumName },
                success: function (data, textstatus) {
                    var _html = "";
                    if (data != '') {
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                            _html += '<div class="child-service-container">';
                            _html += '<div class="child-service-head">';
                            _html += '<a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="' + val.FullImage + '">';
                            _html += '<img src="' + val.ThumbImage + '" alt="' + val.ThumbImage + '" height="250" width="250" />';
                            _html += '</a></div></div>';
                        });
                        items.push(_html);
                        $('.image-album-container .row').append(items);
                        items = [];


                    }
                    else {
                        page = -1;
                    }

                    inCallback = false;

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    function GetImages(album) {
        $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
        albumName = album;

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetImages",
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: { pageNum: 0, Album: albumName }
        });
        request.done(function (response) {
            $('.main-album-container').hide();

            var _html = '<div class="service-wrapper"><div class="row">';
            $.each(response, function (key, val) {
                _html += '<div class="child-service-container">';
                _html += '<div class="child-service-head">';
                _html += '<a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="' + val.FullImage + '">';
                _html += '<img src="' + val.ThumbImage + '" alt="' + val.ThumbImage + '" height="250" width="250" />';
                _html += '</a></div></div>';
            });
            _html += ' </div></div>';
            items.push(_html);
            $('.image-album-container').html(items)
            items = [];

        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });

    }
```

[I want Images upload there slowely when scrolling this is front view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x15jW.png)

Comment: can  any One give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Everything happens in the following lines of code

```
if ($(window).scrolltop() == $(document).height() -  $(window).height()) { 
   loadprojectdata(url); 
}
```

Here it starts loading only after you scrol to the bottom of the page according to this formula. Change this to trigger `loadprojectdata(url);` method at the point you want it to load.